# Solidity mapping not returns an array in a struct

Tags: struct, mapping, ethereum, solidity

The Solidity's mapping not returns an array inside a struct (when call `mapping_data()`, the data variable is undefined).

Just be able to read it from `read()` function.

Does anyone know a reason?

```
    struct structPackage
    {
        uint256 ui;
        string[2] data;
    }

    // the mapping_data(address) is not includes data variable, undefined.
    mapping(address => structPackage) public mapping_data;

    constructor()
    {
        structPackage storage data_package = mapping_data[msg.sender];
        data_package.data[0] = "test1";
        data_package.data[1] = "test2";
    }

    // This function shows data as expected, [ 'test1', 'test2' ].
    function read() external view 
    returns (structPackage memory)
    {
        structPackage storage data_package = mapping_data[msg.sender];
        return data_package;
    }
```

[Tested on Remix, mapping_data doesn't return the array inside struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5dNg.png)

Answer (score 1):

When a `struct` is used as value inside a `mapping`, the getter function of the `mapping` will ignore the `mappings` or `arrays` used inside the `struct`, because there is no easy way to provide keys or indexes to get the specific element from array or mapping. This mechanism exists to avoid high gas costs when returning an entire array or entire mapping.
Hence, if you want to access a complete array or mapping inside a struct (which is used as a value in a mapping which is public) make separate specific getters as required(Similar to as you wrote your `read` method). 
 
[Read Getter Functions docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#getter-functions)

[Read a similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12792)