# solidity array in struct

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
contract TEST {
   
    struct testStruct {
        address[] testArr;
    }

    mapping(address => testStruct) public testMap;
  
    function addToStruct() public {
        test storage a = testMap[msg.sender];

        a.testArr.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getStruct() public view returns(address[] memory){
        return testMap[msg.sender].testArr;
    }
}
```

When i call `await testMap(my address)`  after calling `await addToStruct()`, it seems that the array defined in the structure is not returned. However, if you define a get function like `getStruct()` and look up information within the contract, it seems to bring information well, so is there anyone who can explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the specific JS code that you use to invoke the functions.

Comment: @devChoi could this be the issue? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72124271/solidity-mapping-not-returns-an-array-in-a-struct#:~:text=When%20a%20struct%20is%20used,element%20from%20array%20or%20mapping.)

Comment: oh thanks it solves my question completely!

Comment: @devChoi Please answer your own question and close this issue!