# Get array from struct

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

so I have this contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

    struct Universe{
        uint256 year;
        uint64[3] space;        
    }

contract myContract {

    mapping(address => Universe) public myUni;
    
    function setSomething(uint256 _year, uint64[3] memory _space) public {
            Universe memory testUni = Universe({
            year: _year,
            space: _space
        });
        myUni[msg.sender] = testUni;
    }
}
```

And I am currently trying to test if the array is being passed correctly with truffle:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

const myContract = artifacts.require("./1_Storage.sol");

contract('myContract', (accounts) => {
    

    it('checks if setSomething works', async () => {
        const myContractInstance = await myContract.new();

        const spaceData = [6000, 6000, 6000];

        await myContractInstance.setSomething(2543,spaceData,{from: accounts[1]});

        const myPassedData = (await myContractInstance.myUni(accounts[1]));
        console.log(myPassedData);
        console.log(spaceData);
    });
});
```

The issue is, that I am not able to get `spaceData` passed into the function and I don't know why. The `console.log(myPassedData);` shows me only the year and when I try something like `console.log(myPassedData.spaceData);` it says undefined.

Comment: Refer..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72124271/solidity-mapping-not-returns-an-array-in-a-struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sms for the link. As stated in the solidity Documentation:

> If you have a public state variable of array type, then you can only
> retrieve single elements of the array via the generated getter
> function. This mechanism exists to avoid high gas costs when returning
> an entire array.

So I had to write a Getter-Function inside of the Contract to be able to access the array:

```
function getUniverseArray(address _address) public view returns (uint64[3] memory) {
    return myUni[_address].space;
}
```